# UISearchBar displaying UITableView with a detailed view

Tags: ios, xcode

Okay so what I have right now is two arrays with data.

`myArray1` has a long list of headings and `myArray2` has a long list of descriptions. The relevant description for the heading is located in the adjacent point of the array. For instance if 'Water' is at one point in my `Array1`, then 'Is a drinkable fluid' would be at the same point, but in `myArray2`.

THEN `myArray1` is displayed into a `UITableView` and when you click which ever entry, this passes the row number you have clicked into another view which loads, then on that view there is a textfield which is loaded with `myArray2 objectAtIndex:` whatever index was passed across.

This all works fine! so where is the question? I have been trying to implement a search bar like shown in this tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlhrYJxE_rY

But now my search results are displayed in the `UITableView` and when clicked the row that is passed is not specific to `myArray2` because they are different sizes and I am getting the wrong description!!

So, how can I either store my data with the heading and description in the same entity? or how can I avoid search results truncating the actual table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index of object in the array and then pass this index to next controller to show the description.You can get index as

```
NSUInteger index = [array1 indexOfObject:@"water"];
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you search in UITableview, the indexpath in UITableview is different than in results table of uisearchbar. So if you have a custom cell you can add a property in it like indexInNormalTable set it in cellforrowatindexpath: and use that (indexInNormalTable) as index instead of the actual row index.So when you pass that index,you will get the proper corresponding object in your myArray2.

Comment: But my search results are in the same UITableView. It is just updated everytime the text in the search bar is changed. So I have another array being displayed which is myArray3 which is the search results... so the index passed will be different.

Comment: Ya..but say in your default UITableView your object water is at index path.row 4.now when you search for water in your UISearchBar water will be at position 1 i.e index path.row 1.So that index being passed to your next view will be wrong and you will get the wrong result. so you will need to define & set a custom property if you want to pass the index from the default UITableView.